# Dynamic page/replace content and jQuery conflict

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, dynamic

I've read several posts on SO on similar subjects, but was unable to dissect and get my code to function the way I want it too.

I'm creating an app where page content is changed and replaced dynamically. This is the link to the plug-in I used (yes, I tried contacting the developer who programmed the script, but to no-avail).
(css-tricks.com/dynamic-page-replacing-content)

It all works the way it should until I try implementing separate jQuery within {div id="guts"}. For example, I'm trying to add this script, but it's not activating. In fact, no other jQuery script will work within this DIV.
(digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin)

There appears to be some conflict, especially with the hashchange script. I believe this is the source. If I disable the hashchange/dynamic page script, the masked input script works like it should.

Here's the link to the application I'm working on. This is with the hash-change activated. And if you click the menu items, it changes as it should. However, the masked input does NOT work - and it should active on the "phone number" input field.
http://socialbungy.com/newsite/sweeps_temp_facebook/TAB_TEMP1/#enter.php

If you remove the hashmark in the URL, the page loads and the masked input on the phone number field now works as it should, however the dynamic page functionality is gone.
http://socialbungy.com/newsite/sweeps_temp_facebook/TAB_TEMP1/enter.php

So I know this is the problem, I just can't figure out how to prevent the conflict. If you look at the page source of /#enter.php you'll notice the source code for /index.php, not /enter.php. It think this is also a factor. Is this why the script not initiating?

If you guys (and gals?) need my code posted here, which would be a lot, I will. Figured it might be easier to assist with the links, so you can see the structure.

What am I doing wrong? Btw, the pages may be php, but there's no php code within it.

**EDIT:**
Here's the suspected bad code.

```
$(function() {
var reloadMask = function reloadMask() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#phone").mask("(999) 999-9999");
    });
}
var newHash      = "",
    $mainContent = $("#appContent"),
    $pageWrap    = $("#page-wrap"),
    baseHeight   = 0,
    $el;        
$pageWrap.height($pageWrap.height());
baseHeight = $pageWrap.height() - $mainContent.height();    
    $("nav").delegate("a", "click", function() {
        window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");
        return false;
    }); 
    $("#buttonWrap").delegate("a", "click", function() {
        window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");
        return false;
    });    
$(window).bind('hashchange', function(){    
    newHash = window.location.hash.substring(1);        
    if (newHash) {
        $mainContent
            .find("#guts")
            .slideToggle(500, function() {
                $mainContent.hide().load(newHash + " #guts", function() {
                    $mainContent.slideToggle(500, function() {
                        $pageWrap.animate({
                            height: baseHeight + $mainContent.height() + "px"
                        });
                    });
                    $("nav a").removeClass("current");
                    $("nav a[href="+newHash+"]").addClass("current");                       
                });
            });
    };        
});    
$(window).trigger('hashchange');
reloadMask();
```

});

Comment: "need my code posted here, which would be a lot" - A good first step is to reduce the code.  Try to reproduce the problem with as little code as possible.  Many times this will bring you to a solution.

Comment: I edited my original post to include the suspected problematic code. But "a lot" of code, I meant the app structure. :)

Comment: The problem, from our perspective (and hopefully I'm wrong and somebody is composing an answer as we speak), is that this question currently boils down to: "Here's a massive wall of code.  Something's wrong with it.  Please tell me what's wrong and where."  You need to do some debugging.  For example, in your "suspected bad code" why is it suspected to be bad?  If you debug into it, where does it deviate from expected behavior?  Remove code that isn't relevant to the problem one piece at a time until you've narrowed down the problem.

Comment: I've debugged and the script posted is certainly where the problem lies. I've tried debugging the code, as you suggest, but I'm no jQuery expert. Hence the need for help...

Comment: Posting on here is certainly a last resort. I'm a avid learner and always prefer to troubleshoot and figure out problems on my own to prevent future issues, etc. I assure you I'm not looking for an easy outas many come on here looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out!! Still buggy on  some scripts, but it works. I've added comments to a portion of dynamicpage.js script below. Enter your new scripts there and it will re-fire them on content load.

```
$(window).bind('hashchange', function(){    
    newHash = window.location.hash.substring(1);        
    if (newHash) {
        $mainContent
            .find("#guts")
            .slideToggle(500, function() {
                $mainContent.hide().load(newHash + " #guts", function() {
                    $mainContent.slideToggle(500, function() {
                        $pageWrap.animate({
                            height: baseHeight + $mainContent.height() + "px"
                        });
                    });
                    $("nav a").removeClass("current");
                    $("nav a[href="+newHash+"]").addClass("current");

                    //RE-FIRE OTHER SCRIPTS HERE

                });
            });
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery functions probably won't work on some objects, because this particular objects were not a part of the content, at the time the functions were loaded.

Try wrapping these functions in another function,  for instance:

```
var reloadAllFunctions = function reload() {
 // all the important functions
}
```

And call reloadAllFunctions() after you make the AJAX call [ .load() ].

Comment: Thanks, let me try this. Where/how do you want me to call the reloadAllFunctions() after the AJAX call?

Answer (score 0):

If the input-mask is the only thing that doesn't work, try putting just this code in the same file as your pageloaderscript (I believe it is dynamicpage.js). You can put it anywhere, as long it's not in the the pageloader-function.

```
var reloadMask = function reloadMask() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#phone").mask("(999) 999-9999");
    });
}
```

Next, add ' reloadMask(); ' on the last line of your script, after '$(window).trigger('hashchange');' .

Good luck.

Comment: Hi Eric, thanks for the help! It's greatly appreciated. It doesn't appear to have fixed the issue. Not sure where to go from here. I've updated the code in my original post.